# xampp(phpmyadmin) using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So i'm trying to make a phonebook for my project. I can't seem to get the update code. It keeps on returning the error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`. Which I already know.

Why is it not possible to update only one column?

I have columns: `name, tel#, mobile#, address`

Here's my code for updating my selected column that returns the error

```
 Dim sqlvalue As String = "update entries set Tel. # = 
 ('" & txtNewTel.Text & "') where name = '" & txtName.Text & "'"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose your field name `Tel. #` in backticks so MySQL will recognize this is a field and not some nonsensical formula or string.

```
Dim sqlvalue As String = "UPDATE entries SET `Tel. #` = '" & txtNewTel.Text & "' WHERE `name` = '" & txtName.Text & "'"
```

I also added backticks around the field `name` since that is often times a protected key word. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: thanks sir i'm trying to figure out how to add that tick thing lol i keep entering '" "' i thought it was the same thanks again